# What does "on the clock" mean/imply here and why?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms, implication

I have checked the dictionary, **"on the clock" means** :

1) Working or getting paid

2) Of a taxi (and by extension, its driver), currently engaged to carry a passenger and having an active meter.

3) Currently displayed on a motor vehicle's speedometer or odometer .

I'm **not sure which explanation fits the context best**; **seems to me "working" is a choice?**

In the context, **I feel like** **when Tony said " “We’re on the clock.” ,** **he means "We don't have enough time/ the clock is ticking/ it's urgent".**

Could anyone help me to understand **what exactly** did Tony want to express here: **working or urgent? or something else?**

Here is the sentence in the context:

> “Shut it down, Dr. Selvig,” Tony said. He hovered near the machine,
>   hoping Selvig wouldn’t notice the way his thrusters were hiccupping.
>   He was having trouble maintaining consistent thrust.
>
> “It’s too late!” Selvig cried. “She can’t be stopped now! She wants to
>   show us something! A new universe.”
>
> “Okay,” Tony said. Clearly Selvig was beyond reason.
>
> Tony blasted the machine with his repulsors, but it was surrounded by
>   a force field of some kind. The reflected energy knocked him back and
>   also sent Selvig and his computer flying across the rooftop.
>
> “The barrier is pure energy,” Jarvis said. “It’s unbreakable.”
>
> “Yeah, I got that,” Tony said. “Plan B.” He saw Loki on the walkway
>   that led from the landing pad into the penthouse.
>
> “Sir, the Mark Seven is not ready for deployment,” Jarvis said.
>
> “Then skip the bells and whistles,” Tony said. “**We’re on the
>   clock.**” He sure couldn’t take on Loki and the Chitauri, whatever
>   they were, in the suit he was wearing. It was barely hanging together.
>
> The Avengers I

Comment: Cross site dupe: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63948/meaning-of-im-kind-of-on-a-clock-here

Comment: @ CinCout，thanks for the quote. I remember that scene in the FRIENDS vividly. The difference between "on a clock" and "on the clock" is exactly what bothers me here in the avengers. Because I feel like Tony's situation is urgent and he's kind of asking Jarvis to hurry plan b.  I don't get Tony's point of "on the clock"––'working'. Was Tony trying to be funny? making a joke or something?

Comment: Perhaps "On the clock" is a chess reference, meaning that the clock is running, and there's not much time left.  Also, I'm an American, and I've never heard the phrase "on a clock" before

Answer (score 3):

You are correct.  This is a variation of meaning number one.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_the_clock) has some definitions that help:

> on the clock [prepositional phrase]
>
> - (sports) **In the** official **time remaining** in a game or other sporting event.
>
>   > With only three seconds on the clock and the Knicks about to win, 102-96, in their playoff opener against the Philadelphia 76ers at Madison Square Garden last night, Rick Pitino enjoyed the moment. [1989, Dave Anderson, "Sports of the Times: Jackson Hits 'Biggest Shot Of My Life'," New York Times, 28 April (retrieved 20 Apr. 2009)]
> - (chiefly sports drafts) Under scrutiny due to **having to make a decision or produce results** within a set period of time.
> - Remunerated per unit of time.

The passage is saying that there is an extreme *time pressure* to complete something.

People speak about being "on the clock" when they work at a job where you "punch in and punch out" on a time clock.  Such jobs often create tangible results (like in a factory) in a set amount of time, and the speaker is saying they need to produce tangible results.

In this case, the reward may not be a paycheck -- it's whatever the *Avengers* characters are trying to do.

Comment: thanks for the explanation:) Can I understand it in this way: Tony means "we are working––kind of in the middle of saving the world"? AND, he didn't mean "on a clock", right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  You could also say the Avengers are under **time pressure** to save the world.

Comment: @user86301 No, it *only* means that there is time pressure. Interpreting it as *working* (in the sense of getting paid) is beside the point. It would be said just as easily if he were relaxing and  *playing a game*, but trying to beat a high score before the clock ran out.

Comment: @Jason Bassford, then it's really confusing for me, back to where I was. can I understand it in this way: "on the clock", meaning "the remains time (of a sport)", which leads to the implication in this context as "time pressure- don't have much time left"?  but  according to CinCout, and the cross site he quoted above(see the comment above),  "on the clock" is not the same as " on a clock", the later means "don't have much time left.

Comment: @user86301 The phrase has multiple meanings. What it means in any particular case is based on context, In the context of the scene in *The Avengers*, it just means that Tony doesn't *have time* to sit around, worrying about bells and whistles. The actual article used (*the clock* or *a clock*) is mostly irrelevant in general, and it wouldn't have made any difference in this case if Tony had said *we're on **a** clock* instead.

Comment: @ Jason Bassford，thanks a lot:) if the article is not a key factor here, then it would make total sense.